# I'm trying to make the click only work 4 times and then not work afterwards although I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to make the click only work 4 times and then o the opposite once that is finished although I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   i=0;
   if(i<3){
     $('#nums').click(function(){
       $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'-=384px'},'300');
       i++;
     });        
   }else{
     $('#nums').click(function(){
       $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'+=384px'},'300'); 
     });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the .click around the "if else".
Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('#nums').click(function(){
    if(i<3){
        $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'-=384px'},'300');
    i++;
        }else{
        $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'+=384px'},'300');    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this makes i a local variable of the callback, resetting it to 0 on every click.

Comment: whops you´re right. should set the variable before the click.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider putting the logic inside the event handler instead:

**HTML**

```
<button>test</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var timesClicked = 0;

$("button").on("click", function(){
    timesClicked++;

    alert(timesClicked);
    //Insert the code you want to execute when the button is clicked here.


    if(timesClicked >= 4){
        $(this).off("click").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGvcv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this maybe:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('#nums').click(function () {
        if (i < 3) {

            $('#pic').stop().animate({
                top: '-=384px'
            }, '300');
            i++;
        } else {
            $('#pic').stop().animate({
                top: '+=384px'
            }, '300');
           //$(this).off('click');// you could want to unbind it or not, i don't know...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The document ready function is only called once, so you won't ever loop trough your if(i<3) but once. You should set the condition into your click function like this:

```
    var i=0;
    $('#nums').click(function(){
         console.log('click', i);
         if(i<3){
              $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'-=384px'},'300');
              i++;
         }else{
              $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'+=384px'},'300');    
         }
   });
```

I would even suggest something like this instead:

```
    var i=0;
    $('#nums').click(function(){
        console.log('body click', i);
        var target_top = (i < 3) ? '-=384px' : '+=384px';
        $('#pic').stop().animate({top: target_top},'300');
        i++;
    });
```